# SBT evicts older jar which is a required transitive dependency

Tags: cassandra, sbt

My project uses Akka with Cassandra Persistence actors and also use Janusgraph with Cassandra as the data store and Elastic as the index engine. Adding “com.typesafe.akka” %% “akka-persistence-cassandra” % “1.0.0” as a dependency causes my Janusgraph test to fail with: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter. Without the Cassandra Persistence there is a transitive dependency loaded: io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core 3.2.2, but with the Cassandra Persistence added the metrics-core 3.2.2 is evicted in favour of io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core 4.0.5, which cause my Janusgraph set-up to fail, since it relies on the older jar. I am not sure what sbt magic happens and if I can use both jars. How can I prevent the eviction of the older jar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-jmx" % "4.0.5"` to your test dependencies. This artefact includes the JmxReporter, which was included in `metrics-jvm` previously.

Comment: The path to the JMXReporter differs between the the 2 versions: 4.0.5 uses:  com/codahale/metrics/jmx/JmxReporter whereas 3.2.2 uses:  com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter.  Not sure why they decided to that?

Comment: In that case, try overriding the dependency explicitly: `dependencyOverrides += "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-jmx" % "3.2.2"` and hope that the core metrics versions are compatible.